# S3API: Delete object metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I run

```sh
aws s3api head-object --bucket models.huggingface.co --key bert/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ROMANCE/config.json
```

I get two lines of output:

```
 bytes  1113    text/plain  "13ca8d49ee7f02a26f935cb4a60e6557"  Tue, 12 May 2020 22:39:10 GMT   jAI94kJ_exk0tG6z0Yr.Rea4_j0g02Ih
METADATA    atime:1589321950/ctime:1589321949/gid:1007/gname:shleifer/md5:13ca8d49ee7f02a26f935cb4a60e6557/mode:33188/mtime:1589321949/uid:1006/uname:shleifer
```

Is it possible to delete this metadata on S3 programatically? So that if I ran a get command again I would receive no metadata?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with formatting in your question. Nevertheless, the [head-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) returns the following structure (example):

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "ContentType": "text/html",
    "LastModified": "Thu, 16 Apr 2015 18:19:14 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 77,
    "VersionId": "null",
    "ETag": "\"30a6ec7e1a9ad79c203d05a589c8b400\"",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

Thus, to delete the `Metadata` you could use `jq` as follows:

```
aws s3api head-object \
    --bucket models.huggingface.co \
    --key bert/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ROMANCE/config.json \
    | jq -M 'del(.Metadata)'
```

which should produce (example):

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "ContentType": "text/html",
    "LastModified": "Thu, 16 Apr 2015 18:19:14 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 77,
    "VersionId": "null",
    "ETag": "\"30a6ec7e1a9ad79c203d05a589c8b400\""
}
```

Comment: I updated to clarify my question. I want to delete the metadata on the server, not in the output of my bash command.

Comment: I too would like to know how to delete metadata from the object. So far all I've found is setting the metadata when creating the object in the first place :-(

Comment: As far as I know, one can delete the metadata by [copying the object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) to itself and assigning new empty Metadata